# do both values of one predictor have to be observed for every value of the second predictor to include them in 2-way anova?

Tags: r, missing-data, anova

I am trying to find out whether there is a difference in the exit date of a commonly occupied area of two types of fish from data collected over several years.

I believe year has some influence on the exit date, however I do not have observations of both types of fish in every year that was monitored. To do include year as a second predictor in a two-way anova, do I have to filter the data to only include years where both types of fish were observed?

Here is my data.

```
df<-data.frame(type = c(rep('C',42),rep('S',19)),
Year = c(2012, 2008, 2008, 2012, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2016, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2018, 2015, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014,2015),
exit = c(195, 204, 216, 183, 194, 192, 195, 194, 190, 181, 191, 191, 196, 210, 216, 209, 193, 188, 194, 187, 186, 186, 149, 182, 197, 173,185, 182, 198, 189, 183, 177, 190, 198, 208, 190, 204, 185, 188, 189, 205, 179, 175, 180, 188, 191, 173, 186, 191, 196, 196, 192, 207, 192, 185, 176, 190, 192, 175, 196, 200))
```

I have tried reading requirements for an anova but can't find a case that matches mine. Results of my searches suggested using imputations, but I am not sure if that fits my situation or if I need to use a non-parametric test. I have read a lot of material and am overwhelmed and would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or suggest an appropriate forum to read. Working in R.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of.

Best practice if you're going to think about inferences on main effects in the presence of interactions:

```r
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
```

You can get away with "type 2" comparisons:

```r
car::Anova(lm(exit~factor(Year)*type, data = df, type = "3"))
Note: model has aliased coefficients
      sums of squares computed by model comparison
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: exit
                  Sum Sq Df F value  Pr(>F)  
factor(Year)      2471.7 10  2.3725 0.02325 *
type                 3.6  1  0.0341 0.85428  
factor(Year):type  239.2  3  0.7653 0.51934  
Residuals         4792.3 46
```

But "type 3" comparisons don't work/will be harder:

```r
car::Anova(lm(exit~factor(Year)*type, data = df), type = "3")
Error in Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

From `?car::Anova`:

> The designations "type-II" and "type-III" are borrowed from SAS,
> but the definitions used here do not correspond precisely to those
> employed by SAS.  Type-II tests are calculated according to the
> principle of marginality, testing each term after all others,
> except ignoring the term's higher-order relatives; so-called
> type-III tests violate marginality, testing each term in the model
> after all of the others. This definition of Type-II tests
> corresponds to the tests produced by SAS for analysis-of-variance
> models, where all of the predictors are factors, but not more
> generally (i.e., when there are quantitative predictors).  Be very
> careful in formulating the model for type-III tests, or the
> hypotheses tested will not make sense.

Comment: These are really [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) questions ... please post there?